# opening pdf with evince in chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I'd like to open pdf files using evince on Ubuntu (not using the pdf plugin). I've tried editing mailcap and xdg-mime but both don't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

#### Opening a PDF in an external viewer such as Evince...

Google's branded Chrome browser includes the Chrome PDF Viewer plugin that displays PDFs in a new browser tab. The Chromium browser does not because [Chrome PDF Viewer contains some proprietary code](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome). Instead, Chromium acts as described below (by default, presents a Save File prompt).

*(Only confirmed to work under Ubuntu Linux 10.04 (Lucid), Chromium 18.0.1025.151)*

In Chromium... Settings >> Under the Hood >> Downloads...

The *Download Location* should be a directory where it won't be a problem if some PDF files you don't really want to keep wind up there, (such as ~/Downloads).

Setting... *[ ] Ask where to save each file before downloading?*

- if checked, clicking on a PDF will open the Save File dialog.
- if not checked, clicking on a PDF will immediately download it to the *Download Location* directory.

In the lower-left corner, a blue arrow will briefly appear, followed by the prompt...

```
    This type of file can harm your computer. Do you want to
    keep {filename} anyway? [Discard]  [Keep]
```

If you click on [Discard]...

- The file will not be saved to your Downloads folder
- The file will not be opened in any PDF viewer
- You will be left with a blank tab
- Click the Back arrow to return to the page containing the link to the PDF

If you click on [Keep]...

- **If not set to Auto-open PDFs**

  - The PDF file will be downloaded while a progress button is updated in the lower-left corner of the browser
  - Click on the filename at the left end of the button to open the PDF file in the external viewer (i.e. Evince)
  - The external viewer is designated by the system-wide mimetype configuration file(s) which are one or more of...

    - /etc/mime.types
    - /etc/mailcap
    - ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
  - If you click on the down-arrow at the right end of the button you get four options...

    - *Open*

      - Same as clicking on the filename.
    - *[ ] Always open files of this type*

      - Check box to automatically open files of this type, on completion of download, using the external viewer.
    - *Show in folder*

      - Opens the Download Location directory with the default system file browser such as Nautilus or PCManFM.
    - *Cancel*

      - Aborts the download.
      - Grayed out on download completion.
- **If set to Auto-open PDFs** (*[ X ] Always open files of this type*)

  - **The PDF file will be downloaded silently and then opened with external viewer (i.e. Evince)**
  - The PDF will remain in the Download Location directory after the external viewer is closed.
  - Manually delete the PDF by one of...

    - Click Remove from list on the chrome://downloads page.
    - Use the File Browser.

  - At Settings >> Under the Hood >> Downloads

    - The following option will be active (not grayed out)...

      ```
      You have chosen to open certain file types automatically after downloading.
                        [Clear Auto-opening Settings]
      ```
    - There is no option to clear the Auto-open for just PDFs or any other individual filetypes.
    - To clear Auto-open for all filetypes, click on the button...
      `[Clear Auto-opening Settings]`
    - Then reapply any Auto-opens desired

**Supplemental**
Setting the default download location to a temporary directory, like /tmp/downloads, also works well. The PDF will be deleted on next reboot unless you explicitly move it or save it elsewhere.